# Content summaries - sections

Tags: macros, thesis

I'm currently writing up my thesis and I have a section "content summary" in my introduction section. This gives an indication to what each section contains and is about. At the minute, each chapter / section is in text files, "introduction.tex", "background.tex" etc..

My question is whether or not, in each of the chapter ".tex" files - Can I add a tag like "\contentsummary" for each chapter which then get's inserted to the "content summary" section within the introduction file?

Sorry if this does not make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{contsummary}[1]
  {\@nameuse{collect*}{contsum}{\par}{\par}{\subsection*{#1}}{}}
  {\@nameuse{endcollect*}}
\makeatother

\definecollection{contsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Contents summary}
\includecollection{contsum}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{contsummary}{Test section one}
This is the description of the first section. Here we add some more text for the example
\end{contsummary}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{contsummary}{Test section two}
This is the description of the second section. Here we add some more text for the example
\end{contsummary}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{contsummary}{Test section three}
This is the description of the third section. Here we add some more text for the example
\end{contsummary}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I declared a collection `contsum`. For each `\section`, use the `contsummary` environment (which will add its contents to the collection) to enclose the corresponding summary. In the section containing the summaries all you have to do is to invoke `\includecollection{contsum}`. The mandatory argument for the `contsummary` environment is used to produce a heading in the contents summary section.

Comment: Yes this works :) Is it possible to have for example \textbf{Background Section} \\ This section provides the background..` so basically it would auto generate the header titles for the content?

Comment: @user1326876 Sure. I modified the environment definition so now it has one mandatory argument in which you provide the title; this is automatically formatted as a proper heading in the contents summary.